# Can Facebook provide an API for chat (Messenger)?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, facebook, message

I am building a Wordpress website where there will be users who are clients and users who are specialists in a specific area that can be hired for a service by the clients. The owner wants the clients and specialists to be able to live chat with each other, there is no interest in having the users talk with the owner or a bot like you see with many sites using Facebook Messenger. Can the Facebook Messenger API handle this user to user messaging? They will be logged into the site using the Facebook login and their accounts are linked to their Facebook account. Or is there another tool that could handle this that I may not have thought of?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to act on user's behave. But here is a workaround: https://github.com/Schmavery/facebook-chat-api

> This API is the only way to automate chat functionalities on a user account. We do this by emulating the browser. This means doing the exact same GET/POST requests and tricking Facebook into thinking we're accessing the website normally. Because we're doing it this way, this API won't work with an auth token but requires the credentials of a Facebook account.

Comment: There are severe security concerns related around the method of how Schmavery/facebook-chat-api works.
in short 3rd parties can easily log your messages and invade on your privacy without FaceBook having any control of your data. I would highly advise not to use this API even if its the only current solution.

Comment: I don't need it to be automated. I want it so that when a client wants to contact a specialist and both are users in my database, they can click a button to give them a Messenger window that will send a FB message to the specialist using their Email account.

Comment: In this case, a Messenger iframe may be enough.

Comment: Check this out too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin